# wolframalpha result stopiteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, stopiteration

I getting an error for my below code:

```
import wolframalpha

ask = input("Question:- ")
app_id = "E82747-Y2LGY6EKH3"

client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

res = client.query(ask)

answer = next(res.results).text

print (answer)
```

Error I am getting:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    answer = next(res.results).text StopIteration
**
```

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: please format your code and then explain your issue

Comment: Please re-take the [tour], read [ask], and then *ask a question*. You only throw (unformatted) code at us, without any information about what you try to achieve, what result you expect and what kind of problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code (with the question "temperature of the sun") and it seems to work fine, giving me an answer of 5772 K.

[StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) is raised when there are no more items in the iterable (res.results). What question did you ask, and are you sure it gave an answer?

Try printing `res.results` before the call to `next` to check what it returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `try:` and `except:` block. This should allow you to print something if it doesn't find a result.